# Creating javascript loop in html

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I wanted to make a javascript loop in html like the following:

```js
( if (var i=0; i<10; i++) { )  //<-- JAVASCRIPT

//HTML

( } ) //<-- JAVASCRIPT
```

I tried using the `<% JAVASCRIPT %>` but it won't work for me. Does anyone know who to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this with javascript.

Comment: Take a look at some template engine, and check out what [`if`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) does ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not how javascript works. This is something you would do with PHP.

With javascript, you run it seperately from the html. Then, you create an element within your html as a wrapper to put the javascript generated html into. Like so:

**HTML**

```
<div id="myHTMLWrapper">

</div>

<script>
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");

  var myHTML = '<span class="test">Testing out my script!</span>';

  wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML
</script>
```

**See a working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ncn7koqx/1/)**

Sorry I skipped over the `for` loop by the way. Let me fix it with this update... You could do it like this, you see:

```
<script>
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("myHTMLWrapper");

  var myHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    myHTML += '<span class="test">Testing out my script! loop #' + (i + 1) + '</span><br/><br/>';
  }

  wrapper.innerHTML = myHTML

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`for` loops are control flow and thus cannot be inserted into a static context. Try mapping it, e.g.

```
`<html>` + data.map(function(a) { return `<div>${a}</div>` }).join('') + `</html>`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    //Code here
    }
</script>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

I'd suggest you read a bit before going straight into coding
Either way your script seems deficient and I cant make out what you are trying to do with it.

Check these links if you want to append elements:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/html_append.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp

Comment: This doesn't seem to be what OP asked and won't help him. He apparently thinks you can break the script to render HTML as you would with razor script or PHP....

Comment: Oh, sorry, im updating my answer then.

Comment: Late reply, but I think this answer works.  OP confused `for` with `if`.  The `//Code here` section could be replaced with a `document.write()`.