# Html help -- nested ULs and LIs

Tags: html

I want to achieve something like this:

```
<li><a href="#">Item1</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Item3</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="#">Item4</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <a href="#">Item5</a>
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="#">Item6</a>
                                                        <ul>
                                                            <li> <a href="#">Item7</a> </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li> <a href="#">Item8</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
```

Item 1 etc are pulled from a dictionary which can change based on user input. Below is what I tried with my MVC app in the view:

```
    @foreach (var stp in Model.stepData)
{
        <li><a href="#">@stp.Key</a></li>
        <ul>
            @for (int i = 0; i < stp.Value.Count; i++)
    {
        <li><a href="#">@stp.Value[i]</a></li>

}
        </ul>
}
```

I know I want to add < ul > before the < li > in the @stp.Value loop.. but that needs to be open.. the closing tags need to be after the last one in that iteration is written. So I thought that maybe another for loop to enter the  tag.. but that doesn't work at all. Is it possible for me to achieve this in html? 
code of what I tried:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < stp.Value.Count; i++)
    {
        <ul><li><a href="#">@stp.Value[i]</a></li>

}
@for(int i = 0; i<stp.Value.Count;i++){</ul>}
```

TIA for your help.

Tried the answer below but got it was unable to find the listItems in the current context within the loop and it also complained of too many characters in the character literal when @for was used.

The target framework is .Net Core 2.0; MVC 5

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating javascript loop in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45224174/creating-javascript-loop-in-html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should loop through `stp.Value` and returned each item wrapped in `li` tags rendered within your parent `ul` tag:

```
<ul id="myList">
    // stp.Value items here
</ul>

<script>
    var list = docment.getElementById('myList');
    var listItem = '';

    @for (int i = 0; i < stp.Value.Count; i++){
        listItem += '<li><a href="#">' + @stp.Value[i] + '</a></li>'
    }
    list.innerHTML = listItem;
</script>
```

Most MVC frameworks have their own approach to this but since you didn't specify which framework you are using, the above is a general approach to it using vanilla JS.

Comment: Added an additional example of this in an edit.  It uses a `forEach()` with an arrow function to loop.  It won't run wthin `<script />` tag sadly, OP, but it's always nice to move your `js` in to `js` files for debugging.  Maybe it's just me :)

Comment: OP, this is your answer.  Remember to always pick one as the correct solution :P

Comment: I tried applying the above but I get the following errors:
`1. listItem in the @for does not exist in the current context
2. Too many characters in character literal. `
I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Made slight modification to the answer above so that it works with razor loop
:
`

```
    <script>
        var list = document.getElementById('valueList');
        var listItem = ''; 
        var count = 0;
        @for (int i = 0; i<stp.Value.Count; i++) { 
            <text> 
        listItem += '<ul><li><a href="#">' + '@stp.Value[i]' + '</a>'
        count = i;
            </text>
        }
        for (var i = 0; i <=count; i++) {
            listItem += '</li></ul>'
        }
            list.innerHTML = listItem;

    </script>
```

`