# Dynamically generate tabs and subtabs on a webpage based on count from parent page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an index page that records the number of Usecases(1-4), records no. of scenes(1-x) for each Usecase and every scene has set of same input fields.

Considering that I have the above numbers in javascript variables how do I dynamically load the second page based on the values given in the index page.

Index page where we define use cases and no. of scenes.

Second page which has loaded the page according to the number of use cases and scenes from index page

Use case tab :

```
    <ul role="tablist" class="ibm-tabs" aria-label="Tab navigation">
          <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#">Usecase 1</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#">Usecase 2</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#">Usecase 3</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a role="tab" href="#">Usecase 4</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Scenes :

```
            <li><a aria-selected="true" role="tab" href="#example2b-tab1">Intro Page</a></li>
            <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab2">Scene 1</a></li>
            <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab3">Scene 2</a></li>
            <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab4">Scene 3</a></li>
            <li><a role="tab" href="#example2b-tab5">Scene 4</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Tabs content body with tab contents divs inside a 4-3: -->
<div class="ibm-col-4-3 ibm-col-medium-5-3">
    <div id="example2b-tab1" class="ibm-tabs-content">
      <label for="__REPLACE_ME_1__" class="ibm-textcolor-green-60">Use case description<span class="ibm-required">*</span></label>
      <span>
        <input type="text" value="" size="70" id="first_name" name="first_name" required>
      </span>
```

Comment: Since you have images being uploaded you probably want to do this server side by parsing all the post data. Alternatively you can consider parsing url parameters using javascript to dynamically create all the tabs but keep in mind that there are character length limits in url

Comment: images are wireframes, I want to have this done from the front end, even if done on the server I wanted to know how to modify the webpage to display the use cases and scenes accordingly @charlietfl

Comment: Presumably you are posting all the selected data to server where you would loop over the array of all the scenarios posted. What stack are you using server side?

Comment: index page and second page have related form data that would be sent to the server as a single json object. Post that it would be handled accordingly to store on cloudant from the server side @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

If you are working just for a demo and want to use only frontend then you have to use javascript variables to store the values in the index page and then generate the page with a loop all on front-end.

see this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45224278/10055814)

But for real functionality...
It can be easily done from the server-side.

In the index page where one can actually set values.
One can fetch those values using POST requests.

With the values, received generate the next page at the server using a for loop or something and then return the page.

You might also want to store these values as session variables for a particular client at the server-side.

see this [example](http://geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-for-loop-in-flask/) for doing the loop thing on server side using jinja and flask

Comment: can you please show an example code to loop this using JS and display accordingly on the html page

Comment: Yes okay, first tell me that you are using only frontend and no real data from backend?
Personally for something like this I would use a backend server (flask) and use session variables to store the values. And then use jinja python for loop to create a the html code !!

Comment: index page and second page have related form data that would be sent to the server as a single json object. Post that it would be handled accordingly to store on cloudant from the server side

Comment: Okay, but I will suggest making this a two-step process. The info from the index page is sent to the server and the server delivers the generated next page HTML (using for loop).
Else it will take a lot of code on front end side to do this. Go through the js example to get idea